# Laravel 5.2 Command PHP date() stuck

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to run a command every second (game tick) and I'm doing this by having a command which has while(true) loop with the tick logic + a sleep(1).
Full Code below:

```
public function handle()
{
    $this->setUniverse();

    while(true) {
        $updateStart = microtime(true);
        $this->fleetHandler->update();
        $updateEnd = microtime(true);

        $this->info('Fleets updated for time '. date("d m Y H:m:s") . ' on universe ' . $this->universe);
        usleep(1000000);
    }
}
```

To ensure this command only runs once I have this code in the scheduler

```
$schedule->command('game:fleet:update', ['universe' => $key])
            ->everyMinute()
            ->withoutOverlapping();
```

**The problem**:

What happens is that the time printed by the PHP date() function is always the same except for the seconds. The time 11:02 is always the same too and is reset when I restart the VM.

Example output into console

```
Fleets updated for time 13 02 2017 11:02:57 on universe alpha
Fleets updated for time 13 02 2017 11:02:58 on universe alpha
Fleets updated for time 13 02 2017 11:02:59 on universe alpha
Fleets updated for time 13 02 2017 11:02:00 on universe alpha
Fleets updated for time 13 02 2017 11:02:01 on universe alpha
Fleets updated for time 13 02 2017 11:02:02 on universe alpha
Fleets updated for time 13 02 2017 11:02:03 on universe alpha
```

When I check the system time with `date` everything is normal. Can anybody please tell me what's happening here? Thank you.

Comment: May be just try to start command by cron ? It will start your command every second. And PHP is bad for longlive scripts.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling

Comment: cron doesn't allow a script to run every second.

Comment: "m" stand for months, therefore it is always: 02 (well, in feb.) - change it to "i" in your time. Have a look at this table here as well: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Ok, but you should know, that PHP will run slower on every operation. I don't know why, but when I write web crawler, If i dont restart script every 20-30 min it become slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You and I both missed the timestamp has a typo.

You want `date("d m Y H:i:s")` instead `i = minutes and m  = Months`

Comment: Yes, could this be a PHP bug?

Comment: All the `2` was telling us was that its the `2nd month` The fact that it was `2` minutes past the hour is a tricky coincidence.